# Binding Textblock to a Dictionary value where key is given by the user input

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding

[image]

Above is the desired behavior I'm trying to get. The value in Instrument should be used as a key to access dictionaries that store prices.
Suppose we have some collection of currencies that are presented in an item control like this:

```
<ItemsControl Background="White" Name="currenciesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Currencies}">
```

We define a datatemplate to describe how to present each currency in the list with the following attributes:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbbx" Height="20" Width="60" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstrumentTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrencyInstrument}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Name="purchase_price" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding What do I put here??}">
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="sale_price" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding What do I put here??}"/>
```

For the textblock bindings, I would want to have an expression like PurchaseInstruments[CurrencyInstrument] where PurchaseInstruments is a Dictionary property and CurrencyInstrument is another property storing key value to use in dictionary. How can I achieve this behavior?

Please ignore the poor formatting in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by binding the textboxes directly to the selected value from the combobox. The key insight was encapsulating purchase and sale price within a CurrencyInstrument object so that we can directly access the properties when binding in the textbox. Below is XAML code.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbbx" Height="20" Width="60" Grid.Column="1" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstrumentTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"></ComboBox>
<TextBlock Name="purchase_price" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbbx, Path=SelectedValue.PurchasePrice}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbbx, Path=SelectedValue.SalePrice}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is essentially a KeyValuePair type, so your XAML should look something like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbbx" Height="20" Width="60" Grid.Column="1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InstrumentTypes}" 
      SelectedValue="{Binding CurrencyInstrument}"  
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>

<TextBlock Name="purchase_price" 
       Grid.Column="2" 
       Text="{Binding CurrencyInstrument.PurchasePrice}"/>

<TextBlock Name="sale_price" 
       Grid.Column="3" 
       Text="{CurrencyInstrument.SalePrice}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it inspired me to refactor my design in terms of representing CurrencyInstrument as an object with a purchase price and sale price instead of a key value pair in a dictionary. Now my problem is that I'm currently binding the SelectedValue to a variable in my ViewModel but that causes the instrument type to change for all currencies. However, I want each currency to be able to be changed independently. Would I need to maintain a list of such variables corresponding to each currency?